# large primeng components butcher css in flexbox

Tags: html, css, angular, flexbox, primeng

I have a simple Angular application, with a Navbar on top, a footer on the bottom and some content inbetween

```html
  <div id="app">
    <app-navbar></app-navbar>
    <div id="content">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
      <app-footer></app-footer>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

#app {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#content {
  flex: 1;
}
```

in the content section, I have a tabView wrapped into a row/col setup, like this:

```html
<div class="row ">
  <div class="col-md-12">
     Lorem ipsum works even with very large texts
  </div>
</div>
```

The styling works perfectly, in that when the content section gets larger than the default size of the app, the footer moves down however much it needs.

[image: the way it works well with standard html content]

However, if instead of putting plain HTML/ plain text I place any Primeng components (here: TabView) that are larger than the standard screen size/ standard position of the footer, the styling breaks and the content gets placed **on top** of the footer, instead of **pushing** the footer down.

```html
    <div class="col-md-12"> <-- ENLARGING THIS WORKS
        <p-tabView orientation="top" [activeIndex]="tabIndex" (onChange)="handleChange($event)" class="order-form"
            styleClass="tabview-compo-workbench  height-test">  <-- ENLARGING THIS CAUSES THE ISSUE
            <p-tabPanel class="tabview-panel-workbench" styleClass="tabview-compo-workbench">
                <ng-template pTemplate="header">First Tab</ng-template>
                <ng-template pTemplate="content">
                    some html content
                </ng-template>
            </p-tabPanel>
            <p-tabPanel>
                <ng-template pTemplate="header">Second Tab</ng-template>
                <ng-template pTemplate="content">
                    some html content
                </ng-template>

            </p-tabPanel>
        </p-tabView>

    </div>
```

Is there any way to fix this issue? Worst case programmatically.

[image]

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing your generated code. Try using `min-height` in the `#app` css instead of `height`. If that doesn't fix it, Inspect Element is your new best friend in the whole world.

Comment: thanks for your input. min-height does not help, since the css generally DOES adjust to the content height, just not if the inner element is a primeng component.
Hence why using Inspect Element is of no more help, its just how I was able to figure out what the problem is in the first place. The screenshots explain this better.

Comment: Inspect Element should show the HTML for the final rendered page, including all dynamic content.  If Lorem Ipsum content renders fine, but the dynamic components don't, maybe there's something in the dynamic code that's introducing styles and/or elements you're not expecting.

Comment: "maybe there's something in the dynamic code that's introducing styles and/or elements you're not expecting" <-- well yes, that is why I created this question.
I researched for several hours on this after posting the question, since others seemed to have the same issue but there was no solution. So I finally decided, to implemented a programmatic adjustment of the primeng component height which works, though not the way I hoped it would. I will post the new approach as a separate answer in case others encounter similar issues - or have alternative suggestions.